# How to use an existing google chrome profile with selenium chrome webdriver in python?

Tags: python, selenium, web, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I need to load my full existing google chrome profile with all chrome extensions where i logged in google and site account.
I'm struggling with this code, syntax error somewhere

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('user-data-dir= C:\Users\DMMaxim\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
chromedriver = r"C:\Users\DMMaxim\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe" 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options = chrome_options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

i get this error

```
C:\Users\DMMaxim\Desktop>python ExportbacktestTradingview.py
  File "ExportbacktestTradingview.py", line 21
    chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=C:\Users\DMMaxim\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
                               ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 18-19: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Here is my full code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities
from subprocess import Popen
from time import gmtime, strftime
from os import system
import subprocess
import pyperclip
import datetime
import time
import os
import sys

timer=0
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('user-data-dir= C:\Users\DMMaxim\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
chromedriver = r"C:\Users\DMMaxim\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe" 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options = chrome_options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)

driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/chart/gK6Rq0UH/")
driver.implicitly_wait(90)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="footer-chart-panel"]/div[2]/span[4]""").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(90)
while True:
    driver.implicitly_wait(90)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="bottom-area"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[4]""").click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(90)
    timer=timer+1
    time.sleep(1)
    if timer > 250:
                process1 = subprocess.Popen(['C:/Users\DMMaxim/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python.exe', 'C:/Users/DMMaxim/Desktop/Export backtest Tradingview.py'], shell=True)
                driver.quit()                                             
    driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
    contents = pyperclip.paste()
    filepath = r"C:\Users\DMMaxim\Desktop\DATA.txt"
    with open(filepath, 'w') as f: # 'w' means write mode and we get the file object as f
        f.write(contents)
```

Comment: chromedriver = r"C:\Users\DMMaxim\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chromedriver = r"C:\Users\DMMaxim\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"