# use native google chrome's profile in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I want to use native google chrome's profile in selenium.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.67 Safari/537.36");
options.AddArgument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Profile 1");
options.AddArgument("--profile-directory=Profile 1");

var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(new FileInfo(Application.ExecutablePath).DirectoryName);
            driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
var driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com/profile");
```

But it seems the profile not recognized by selenium. because when it lunch there is no bookmark(that I added in native google chrome) and I already login to `example.com` but when I go to the URL by selenium, the login page appears!

I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179420/can-i-run-selenium-chromedriver-with-cookies-from-actual-chrome-installation) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344560/selenium-point-towards-default-chrome-session) but it does not work!

and this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49460190/how-to-use-an-existing-google-chrome-profile-with-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-p) it seems to work on phyton but I don't know how to change it for chrome.